# 2D Point/Vector Displacement based on Direction and Magnitude

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, coordinate-systems

I'm a little confused with a simulation I'm about to implement soon. I could use a little help in vector displacement (if I got this part right), I'm really dumb at figuring this out. Please consider the following problem I formulated to give you an intuition on what I'm trying to calculate.

#### Problem (Please View Attached Diagram)

Given a point with the following details:

- Initial Coordinate: $(x_1, y_1)$
- Displacement Direction (Always from North): $\theta$
- Displacement Magnitude: $s$ units

What is the new coordinate $(x_2, y_2)$, for the above point being displaced from its initial coordinate $(x_1, y_1)$?

In general, I'd like some sort of formula to compute the new coordinates $(x_2, y_2)$ based on any given initial coordinates $(x_1, y_1)$, displacement angle $\theta$ from North, and some displacement magnitude $s$.

[Problem Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaC36.png)

Angle Convention

Sorry about the weird angle, I'm trying to start from North, $0^o$ and move in a clockwise direction. Therefore, here are some angles:

- North: $0^o$
- North-East: $45^o$
- South: $180^o$
- South-West: $225^o$
- North-West: $315^o$

Comment: Is the angle with north measured in clockwise direction? If it is $45$ NE vs $45$ NW, how will you express it?

Comment: Hi @MathLover, yes it's in clockwise direction. If the angle is 45 NE, I'd express it as $45^o$, if it's 45 NW, it'd be $315^o$ in this case. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: OK or you can also express it as $-\pi \leq \theta \leq \pi$ and $\theta$ is the angle made with north direction. The point $(x_2, y_2)$ will be given by $(x_1, y_1) + s (\sin \theta, \cos \theta)$.

Comment: Okay, I'm still a little confused, sorry. So to simplify, would it be something like this:
$$
\begin{aligned}
(x_2, y_2) &= (x_1, y_1) +s(\sin\theta, \cos\theta) \\
&= (x_1 + s\times\sin\theta, y_1+s\times\cos\theta)
\end{aligned}
$$

So, something like $x_2 = x_1 + s\times\sin\theta$ and $y_2 = y_1+s\times\cos\theta$

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I been scratching my head since hours on this, really appreciate it. I'm going to put this into the simulation now :)